# Project server 2010: If i am trying to login with URL its throwing an error and if i am using it with server name i can access the site

Tags: project-server

[image]

I am trying to access an HTTPS site using and i could not access it please find the image that was the error i am facing with the site

Answer (score 1):

That means, issue with URL as you are able to browse with server name and port number.
Couple of things to check:

- If you are using the Loadbalancer make sure it is working,
- make sure IIS bindings are in Place.
- Check if the DNS is still pointing to the right server
- Check if the SSL certificate is still in placed and bind with Web app.